# run command in autohotkeys n number of time

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

I would like to make my command runs specific number(n) of times in autohotkeys. 
Example:

```
::t::
    send test
return
```

Now you type `t` and press `tab` it prints `test`. I would like to specify number (e.g. 5). So command will type `testtesttesttest` (test 5 times). Pseudo code something like this:

```
::t::n
    send test
return
```

And `n` would be number of times command should run. I'm noob to autohotkeys and I need this fast, and can't find info googling. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::t::
    input, count, I T5, {Enter}
    if count is Integer
    {
        loop, %count%
            send test
    }
return
```

After pressing <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, this will give you 5 seconds to type any number (accept it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, remove digits by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) and immediately send `test` as much times.

See also: [loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm), [input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm)

edit: If you know already how often you want `test` to be sent, you can ofc simply go for

```
::t::
     loop, 10
            send test
return
```

---

> OK it works, but can you make that I type t5 and then tab, or t7, t15, t45, etc... And it runs command 5 times(or n times). So I end with pressing tab

Well, that's something different. You are trying to achieve a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) with out of a variable part. There is no such thing as regular expression hotstrings (`::t[0-9]*::`). Let's build it ourselves then, using a simple [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) (`~t::` instead of `::t::`).

If you are alright with the natural function of <kbd>t</kbd> to be overridden, you can use

```
t::
    input, count, I T5, {Tab}
    if count is Integer
    {
        loop, %count%
            send test
    }
return
```

which is the same as above, but the tab is only neded after the number. Hotkeys (`t::`) don't need any extra trigger keys.

On the other hand, if you want to use <kbd>t</kbd> in normal context as well, but you want <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> be converted into `testtesttesttesttest`, you can use something like the following:

```
~t::
    input, count, I T5 V, {Tab} ; V: input will be visible because if not used as t3{tab}, we want to keep the written input
    if count is Integer
    {   ; if not, than user probably just used t in a normal string context
        ifInString, ErrorLevel, EndKey  ; if input was terminated by {tab}
            send {BS}   ; = {Backspace}
        else {
            return ; you can delete this line. Keep it, if you want t3 to be transformed into testtesttest only after the timeout ran out, even without TAB being pressed.
        }
        send {BS}   ; remove the t
        loop, % strLen(count)
            send {BS}   ; remove the numbers
        loop, % count
            send test
    }
return
```

^ This is basically a variable hotstring.

---

A more beautiful approach for this might be:

```
::t1::send test
::t2::
    loop, 2
         send test
return
::t3::
    loop, 3
         send test
return
```

and so on. But this is sophisticated to realize, obviously.

Comment: OK it works, but can you make that I type `t5` and then `tab`, or `t7`, `t15`, `t45`, etc... And it runs command 5 times(or n times). So I end with pressing `tab`.